# chrome.tabs.onUpdated doesn't consider a refresh an update

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Basically I have 2 popups that I want to set based on the hostname of the URL. If the hostname is outside the options for the 2 popups then i want to grey it out. I've played with declarativeContent but can't figure how to add a popup with the action:  I've also tried to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated which works if you enter the domain or new tab and enter a URL but if you hit refresh it just defaults to the manifest default popup. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use chrome.webNavigation events.

Answer (score 0):

> Use chrome.webNavigation events. – wOxxOm

Thanks!